# Use javascript and ajax to update page

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I'm trying to automatically show content from an external page, using javascript and ajax.  Nothing is shown on the page, or in the error console.  Can anyone see what my problems are?  Thank you so much!
HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Stocks</title>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">                 </script>
            <script src="projectstocks.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div>
        <content id="content">

        </content></div>
        </body>
     </html>
```

projectstocks.js:

```
    window.onload = function() {
var stocks = [];
var content = document.getElementById("content");
update();
setInterval("getData()", 1000);
}

function getData(data) {
content.innerHTML = "";
var tbod = document.getElementById("stocks");
var myTable= "<table id='table' border='1'>";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var obj = data[i];
    for(key in obj){
        console.log(key);
        var value=(obj[key]);
        console.log(value);
        content.innerHTML += ("<tr><td>");
        content.innerHTML += ((obj[key]));
        content.innerHTML += ("<br><br></td></tr>");
    }
}
myTable+="</table>";
}

function update() {
$.getJSON('http://shodor.org/~amalani/AjaxTutorial/stocks/stocks.php?symbols=GOOG+CAT+FB', getData);
 }
```

Thanks again!  This doesn't have to be very fancy, let me know if there's anything I don't need.

Comment: you have an interval calling getData() with no arguments every second. Maybe you should call update() every second...

Comment: data.length is nothing here hence you see nothing.

Comment: You should also consider renaming your getData function to viewData.

Comment: I don't think `content` is in scope within `getData()`. Since it is defined within your `onload` function, the scope is limited to that function.

Comment: @VanCoding, I tried changing function update() {
$.getJSON('http://shodor.org/~amalani/AjaxTutorial/stocks/stocks.php?symbols=GOOG+CAT+FB', getData);
 } to function update() {
$.getJSON('http://shodor.org/~amalani/AjaxTutorial/stocks/stocks.php?symbols=GOOG+CAT+FB', update);
 }  Nothing happened…

Comment: Please read my answer again ;) You should change the function that gets called in an interval and not the callback function for loading the data.

Comment: In your `getData` function you are basically doing nothing in the DOM. You are creating some strings, creating some table row elements but never attaching to the DOM. Please read some basic tutorials on how the DOM works and how you can manipulate it. We cannot help you, sorry. This code is beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getData` is not really getting any data. It's displaying data you pass to it in the first argument.

With `setInterval("getData()", 1000);` you're callin that function repeatedly with no data which will result in no data being displayed.

Instead, you should call the function `update` in that interval. Because this function actually fetches the new data and views it when it's loaded.

**Update**

As @kapa said, getData has also bugs in it. Please check that ;)

1. You're doing `var tbod = document.getElementById("stocks");` for no reason, because you don't use that variable anywhere.
2. You're doing `var myTable= "<table id='table' border='1'>";` and `myTable+="</table>";` for no reason, because you don't use that variable anywhere.
3. You're doing `var tr = document.createElement('tr');` for no reason, because you don't use that row anywhere

And that are not even all of the problems in your code. I recommend you to go over it completely, again ;)

**Update**

Since you seem to search for the finished code, I can tell you how a fixed `viewData` might look like:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");

function viewData(data) {
    var html = "<table id='table' border='1'>"; //we'll store our html in this variable
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        for(var key in obj){
            html += "<tr><td>"; //continue to build our html
            html += obj[key];
            html += "<br><br></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    content.innerHTML= html+"</table>"; //now that the html is finished, define it as our content
}
```

Please note that you always have to call this function with data. For example like this:

```
viewData([{"name":"Google Inc.","symbol":"GOOG","price":59055,"open":58902},{"name":"Caterpillar, Inc.","symbol":"CAT","price":10370,"open":10485},{"name":"Facebook, Inc.","symbol":"FB","price":7491,"open":7519}]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the only problem (although I agree it is a problem). Since OP calls `update()` before `setInterval`, the correct call should have been made initially, and some data should have been shown. This is contradictory to the statement of "Nothing is shown on the page"

Comment: @PatrickQ Nothing should be shown, as `getData` is doing NOTHING that should leave a visible mark in the DOM.

Comment: @VanCoding "bugs" is a very PC way to say "complete gibberish" :).

Comment: @kapa That's basically my point. I probably just phrased it poorly. I was just trying to convey that calling `getData` instead of `update` in the `setInterval` isn't the only (or even primary) problem.

Comment: @PatrickQ We agree then :). But I think the `getJSON` call is fine, only the other lines should be rewritten. I think we cannot do better than close this question (rewriting the whole code would not really help the OP)...